# Domain users cannot change password if domain name is written before username

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, domain-controller, nameserver

we have multiple sites every site has RODC and Headoffice has two RWDC 2008 r2 and 2012 std .

clients are win 7 and win 10 .

domain users cannot change their domain password error the security database on the server does not have computer account .

if they enter pdc name before their user then they can change their password .

Comment: What do the logs show in event viewer under security on both the local PC and the DC?  If you run set from the command prompt what shows as the LOGONSERVER?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, the computer does not have a domain computer account. You might want to remove the computer from domain and join it again.

Comment: Mzhaase the computer in in the domain . they can login to domain but they can't change password . the trust result is also true .

Comment: Something is wrong with the trust relationship. Try removing and re-adding the computer to the domain.

Comment: Mzhaase : it is not with one ,two or ten pc's .the issue is in all domain client which are above 600 users.